# Group Theory Proof

Tags: group-theory

Prove that in any group G, $x^2=x$ has exactly $1$ solution.
For the proof, I know that the identity element $e$ is a solution because $e*e=e$. But how would I prove that that is the only solution?

Answer (score 2):

Well $G$ is a group so there is $y\in G$ so that $yx=e$. So $xx=x\implies x=ex=yxx=yx=e$

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that if $x^2 = x$ and $x$ is an element in a group, then $x$ has an inverse.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** There exists some $x^{-1}$ so that $x^{-1}*x=e$.